# How can I get calendar's add/remove-reminder like functionality in my android application?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am a new to android development. There is add/drop functionality for reminders in a calendar's create event activity (like - and + image buttons).

What steps I can follow to create such a functionality in my activity? For example, by clicking '-' sign image button, (reminder) drop down is removed and by clicking '+' image button, a new drop down is added.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

To be very exact: I want to create my own calendar. So when I click on '+' button, a new activity is opened which have date and time pickers. When date and times are selected on that screen, it returns that data to the launching (main) activity. On main activity, I want to have these date and time slots shown just like reminders are shown in an event activity of calendar.

Comment: I have edited my question, hope you can guide something now. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you want or need. But if you want to dynamically add **widgets(Views)** to a **Layout**, you got several options here. One option would be to put the **widget(View)**, you want to add dynamically, in to a separate layout definition (XML file). Then whenever you want to add this **View** to another **Layout** you use the **LayoutInflater** to create an instance of the **View** from the XML. When you have your instance you can easily add this instance to any **Layout** by using the method `addView(View child)` or any of its overloaded versions.

Comment: That's pretty much the same I was looking for. So what I understand is that whatever I want to add dynamically to my layout screen, I would create an XML for that and then using LayoutInflator, I would add that XML-layout to my main layout? Thanks for your help.